# How to sort an Array in increasing order after squaring each element?

Tags: c++, sorting

My code can get the correct output but it's exceeding the time limit. How can I improve it?

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortedSquares(vector<int>& A) {

        //sorting based on absolute values

        for(int i=0;i!=A.size();++i){
            for(int j=0;j!=A.size();++j){
                if(abs(A[i])<abs(A[j])){
                    int temp=0;
                    temp=A[i];
                    A[i]=A[j];
                    A[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

      //squaring each element

        for(auto &k: A){
            k*=k;
        }
        return A;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::sort` with a custom comparator?

Comment: `std::sort` would be faster than bubble sort (almost anything would be faster than bubble sort), squaring first would probably also make the sorting simpler and faster by removing the need to use `abs`. This isn't even the most efficient implementation of bubble sort, `j` doesn't need to start from `0` each time

Comment: `std::sort` has an average time complexity of O(nlogn) but bubble sort is easily O(n^2). So using `std::sort` is more efficient than bubble sort.

Comment: @Botje I can but I don't want to use it. But I guess I don't have an option. I'll have to go with 'std::sort'

Comment: "I *could* go buy shoes and be back in half an hour, but I'd rather go hunt cows and make the leather myself". The standard library is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever gave you this task played a bit of a trick on you. Your goal is to end up with sorted array of squares -- so why not do away with squaring first? Do that and you can then omit all calls to `abs()`. Maybe that will already get you below the time limit.

The second improvement is a bit of a guess, but worth a try. `A` is not `const` (can't be or you wouldn't be able to sort it). That means that compiler can make fewer assumptions that would help it optimize your code. For example, it can't know that all calls to `A.size()` will return the same value. But you know that, so you can optimize that as well.

The third improvement I suspect compiler already does for you, but why not cleanup that anyway. Why would you initialize `temp` to 0 only to assign it a value in the next line? You can simply initialize it to correct value. Or you could even go as far as using `std::swap()`...

```c
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortedSquares(vector<int>& A) {
        // squaring each element
        for(auto &k: A){
            k*=k;
        }

        // sorting squares
        auto size = A.size();
        for(int i=0; i!=size; ++i){
            for(int j=0; j!=size; ++j){
                if(A[i] < A[j]){
                    int temp=A[i];
                    A[i]=A[j];
                    A[j]=temp;
                   // or replace this block with std::swap(A[i], A[j])
                }
            }
        }

        return A;
    }
};
```

Comment: this is still an inefficient implementation of bubble sorting

Comment: If you're going for efficiency then your choice probably won't be bubble sort.

Comment: No, they should be using `std::sort` but as the whole point of the question was "how can I make this faster" at least making the bubble sort as least slow as possible would be a good idea (and probably make more performance difference than your other changes)

Comment: You're right. I didn't even notice the inner loop going all the way.